# Get Entry.Text from Entry defined in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

trying to write calmly as I am being seriously frustrated by Xamarin right now. I have an Entry that is defined in my MainPage.xaml. It looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestFood"
         x:Class="TestFood.MainPage" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="EATH" TextColor="#FFFFFF" FontSize="64"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="budgetEntry"  Placeholder="Budget" Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="40,0"/>
            <Button Margin="80,0" Text="Search Recipes" Clicked="Button_Clicked">SubmitButton</Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

All I'm trying to do is take the text from the Entry and use it in my MainPage.xaml.cs. Seeing as Xamarin can be quite convoluted, how do I go about this? I've looked at Binding but the documentation is rather poor and doesn't really get you started anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any element with a Name assigned can be referenced from the code behind

```
var txt = budgetEntry.Text;
```